# Positioning background image

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with positioning background image with h1 tag

My code:
      [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw3jrbhc/)

When I put `font-size: 18px` I have desired output but I want to have larger font.

No matter what I type in css I cannot position it as I would like.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you want the image to be? In the center of the title? Or you want the title to be in the middle of the image no matter the size of the font?

Comment: Telling us what you'd like would be a good start.

Comment: Always post your code in your question. You can then *supplement* that with a fiddle.

Comment: Give your `h1` a fixed height property. The reason a larger font size shows the background is because it now has height to it. If after that the line isn't where you want it, use `background-position` and fine tune the px values.

Comment: @Shomz If you change font-size to 18px you will get what I have right now, but I would like to have that with the font 25px

Comment: @BojanPetkovski Yes I would like to have that title in the middle between those dots.

Comment: Yes, I just wrote you a solution that works for every font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave  width to the

```
<h1>
```

tag 
and gave background-size:100%; http://jsfiddle.net/tw3jrbhc/1/

```
.role h1 {
 width:1400px;
background: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/2167bt.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
background-position:center;
background-size:100%;
color: #000;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 15px 0 15px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I want except I need width to be 1030px.

Comment: @Morpheus http://jsfiddle.net/tw3jrbhc/2/ i changed the background size to 120%

Comment: Ok, I'll change it a bit to have a space between the dots and the title. I have one more question: will this be responsive or should I add something? Thank you

Comment: @Morpheus the percentage value will be responsive you can try zooming out or in it will always be at the center

Comment: Ok, will leave it like this. Thank you.

Comment: This breaks when you change the font size... It works only for this specific hard-coded value. Not an ideal solution.

Comment: @Shomz yes because he gave that value in his css

Answer (score 1):

If you want something flexible/controllable that will work with every font size, you should consider using the ::before pseudo-element:

```
.role h1::before {
    content:'';
    background: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/2167bt.png") no-repeat right center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 224px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tw3jrbhc/3/

```css
.role {
    width: 1030px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.role h1 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 15px 0 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
}
.role h1::before {
    content:'';
    background: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/2167bt.png") no-repeat right center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 224px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="role">
     <h1>Loremloremaa Lorembb Loremlorema Loremlor aa Lorema Loremlor</h1>

    </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. ::before basically adds another an element in front of each `.role h1` and here we use that element just to control the background more easily as it can have its own width and everything.